# HashFunction for a "word"

Tags: algorithm

I have the following "word" for which I will need a hashfunction.

A word *w* has the form *w=character[character]digit[digit]* the brackets *[]* mean that those are optional. Characters are *A,B...Z* and digits are *0,1,2...*

So there are 26*26*10*10 =67600 possible words and I need a hashfunction for a table with 220 entries. The division method would obviously work here but I am looking for something that can be more easily calculated

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Why do you need something that "can be more easily calculated" than a standard hash function for strings?

Comment: @Thilo I am practicing for an exam and this is what we have to find

Comment: Considering the optionals, you have 26*27*10*11 possibilities, I think.

Comment: As far as I know, using modulo to finish off one of the algorithms is the standard. What determines the quality of the hash is how you derive the value that you take the modulus of.

Comment: Hint : your word is basically an array of characters (considering the digit also a character) assuming word is in form of String or a char[].  In such a case try seeing the implementation of hashcode() method defined for char[] in Arrays.java.

Comment: What is "the division method"?

Comment: @Dukeling : Using the hash function *x modm* where *m* is the size of the hashtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than 67,600 possible words. You have:

- *character*-*digit* (A9, Q3, etc.): 26*10 (260) possible
- *character*-*character*-*digit* (AA3, BQ5, etc.): 26*26*10 (6,760) possible
- *character*-*digit*-*digit* (A95, G47, etc.): 26*10*10 (2,600) possible
- *character*-*character*-*digit*-*digit*: 26*26*10*10 (67,600) possible

So the total number of possible words is 260+6760+2600+67600 = 77,220

Which is evenly divisible by 220. So your "hash function" can be a simple modulus:

```
bucket = index % 220
```

I don't think you'll find anything easier to calculate than the modulus. You could use a standard string hash code function, but that's going to involve multiple shift and additions, and then likely a modulus at the end. You could use a simple checksum, which is just a few additions, but that's unlikely to give you a good distribution of items in your hash table. Since the total number of possible items is an even multiple of the number of buckets, it'll be hard to beat the modulus in terms of speed or distribution.

By the way, the comment by @Thilo is correct: your total number of possibilities is 26*27*10*11. As you said, the second character and the second digit are optional. If you view the optional property as another possible character (an empty character), then the alphabet for your second character contains 27 items (the 26 alphabetic characters, and the empty character). So words like "A99" are actually of the form:

*character* *empty-character* *digit* *digit*

Answer (score 1):

You might treat your words as an integer in numerical system with the base 36. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36)

But there is an edge case, 'cause you have optional characters, so you need somehow ignore them. You can add an `empty character`(example: #) and during conversion you'll ignore it.

PS. it'll be base-37 numerical system, but the logic remains the same.

Comment: But it's not base-37. And without the optional characters, it's not base-36. You can't really view these values as numbers in a traditional base system, because the valid digits for each position differ.